# Replacing spaces with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem to find a regular expression to replace all spaces in given string:

```
var test = '1 2 3 4';
alert(test.replace(/\s/, ''));
```

The first space is replaced correctly but I want to get the string without any spaces. In the example above I'm expecting "1234".

Comment: Add `g` at the end. `test.replace(/\s/g, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `g` flag for global at the end of your Regular Expression:

```
var test = '1 2 3 4';
alert(test.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

Look at 'flags' on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(test.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

"g" for "global"

Comment: Give an explaination, not just an answer

Comment: Edited : g is for global : it will replace in the whole string, if not, it will just replace the first occurence

Comment: Ah ok. Right, I forgot the flags. Thanks a lot.

Comment: mark as answered please ;)